# How to avoid worker threads being stuck in sem_wait?

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex, semaphore, producer-consumer

I am new to semaphores and wanted to know how to avoid a situation where my worker thread (in a multiple worker single producer problem) is stuck in `sem_wait(&full)`. I also have a mutex lock after this but I doubt that, that is where it is stuck. I know all my tasks are being completed but the threads are not exiting. The producer thread in my program stops sending data once all tasks are done.

For reference... the producer thread...

```
 while (i<number_of_tasks)
    {
        TASK task;   
        task.start_row = i*num_of_rows;
        task.num_of_rows = num_of_rows;
        sem_wait(&empty);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        tasks[in] = task;  
        in = (in+1)%buff_size;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        sem_post(&full);
        i++;
        //printf("%d tasks completed out of %d tasks\n", counter, number_of_tasks);
        if (counter==number_of_tasks)
            break;
    }
```

And ...the worker thread function

```
int i, item, index;
TASK task;
index = *((int*)arg);
int notasks1;
for (i=number_of_tasks; i > 0; i--) {
    //previous code
    sem_wait(&full);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    task=tasks[out];
    out = (out+1)%buff_size;
    //completing task code...
    counter++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    sem_post(&empty);
    printf("%d tasks completed out of %d tasks\n", counter, number_of_tasks);
    if (counter==number_of_tasks)
        break;

}
printf("Worker thread %d has terminated and completed %d tasks\n",index,notasks1);
return NULL;
```

the full code... for reference

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include </usr/include/semaphore.h>
// for sleep
#include <unistd.h>
#include "Mandel.h"
#include "draw.h"

#define BUFF_SIZE   10           /* total number of slots */
#define NP          1           /* total number of producers */
#define NC          5           /* total number of consumers */
#define NITERS      IMAGE_HEIGHT/10           /* number of items produced/consumed */

//int buf[BUFF_SIZE];   /* shared var */


//struct task for storing the tasks the current worker thread has to do
typedef struct task 
{
    int start_row;
    int num_of_rows;
} TASK;
TASK* tasks;

int buff_size; //= 7;
//TASK buff[buff_size];
int in=0;               /* buf[in%BUFF_SIZE] is the first empty slot */
int out=0;              /* buf[out%BUFF_SIZE] is the first full slot */
sem_t full;           /* keep track of the number of full spots */
sem_t empty;          /* keep track of the number of empty spots */
int number_of_tasks;// = IMAGE_HEIGHT/20;
float *pixels;
int num_of_rows;// = 20;
int counter = 0;
// use correct type here
pthread_mutex_t mutex;          /* enforce mutual exclusion to shared data */
/*void *Producer(void *arg)
{
    int i =0;
    while (i<number_of_tasks)
    {
        if (counter==number_of_tasks)
            break;
        TASK task;   
        task.start_row = i*num_of_rows;
        task.num_of_rows = num_of_rows;
        sem_wait(&empty);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        tasks[in] = task;  
        in = (in+1)%buff_size;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        sem_post(&full);
        i++;
        if (counter==number_of_tasks)
            break;
    }
    return NULL;
}*/

//function for consumer threads to accesss
void *Consumer(void *arg)
{   
    int i, item, index;
    TASK task;
    index = *((int*)arg);//getting index of thread from argument parsing it into int
    int notasks1;
    //for loop to complete number of tasks per thread
    for (i=number_of_tasks; i > 0; i--) {

        //defining start_compute and end compute to calculate time per task 
        struct timespec start_compute, end_compute;
        float difftime;
        printf("Worker(%d): Start the computation ...\n", index);
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start_compute);
        //calling sem wait to wait for producer thread to fill in tasks for worker threads. will wait if buffer is empty
        sem_wait(&full);
        //calling mutex lock
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        //getting tasks from struct tasks array
        task=tasks[out];
        //incrementing to next task in buffer so that next thread accesses next task
        out = (out+1)%buff_size;
        //calculating pixels for image
        int x, y;
        //printf("start_row... %d, num_of_rows... %d\n", task.start_row, task.num_of_rows);
        for (y=task.start_row; y<task.start_row+task.num_of_rows; y++) 
        {
            for (x=0; x<IMAGE_WIDTH; x++) 
            {
                pixels[y*IMAGE_WIDTH+x] = Mandelbrot(x, y);
            }
        }
        //increasing counter to check if all tasks are done
        counter++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        sem_post(&empty);//informing a producer that a task has been taken out and if tasks are left buffer is empty to add tasks
        //calculating end compute and posting
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end_compute); //end time values for the child processes
        difftime = (end_compute.tv_nsec - start_compute.tv_nsec)/1000000.0 + (end_compute.tv_sec - start_compute.tv_sec)*1000.0;
        printf("Worker(%d):\t...completed. Elapse time = %f ms\n",index, difftime);\
        notasks1++;
        printf("%d tasks completed out of %d tasks\n", counter, number_of_tasks);
        if (counter==number_of_tasks)
            break;

    }
    printf("Worker thread %d has terminated and completed %d tasks\n",index,notasks1);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    buff_size = atoi(args[3]);
    num_of_rows = atoi(args[2]);
    number_of_tasks = IMAGE_HEIGHT/num_of_rows;
    int number_of_workers;
    number_of_workers = atoi(args[1]);
    struct timespec start_time, end_time;
    printf("number_of_tasks...%d\n", number_of_tasks);
    pthread_t idP, idC;
    int index;
    sem_init(&full, 0, 0);//initializing full to zero so that consumer thread knows buffer is empty and waits for producer thread
    sem_init(&empty, 0, buff_size);//initializing empty to buffer size so that producer knows to add that many tasks
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    int i = 0;
    pixels = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float) * IMAGE_WIDTH * IMAGE_HEIGHT);//assigning pixels memory
    //tasks = (TASK*) malloc (sizeof(TASK) *buff_size); 
    //pthread_create(&idP, NULL, Producer, NULL);
    for(index=0; index<number_of_workers/*5*/; index++)
    {
        printf("Worker(%d): Start up. Wait for task!\n", index); 
        pthread_create(&idC, NULL, Consumer, (void*)&index);//creating worker threads to go to consumer function sending their index
    }
    tasks = (TASK*) malloc (sizeof(TASK) *buff_size);    
    //master/producer thread work
    while (i<number_of_tasks)
    {
        TASK task;   
        task.start_row = i*num_of_rows;
        task.num_of_rows = num_of_rows;
        //calling sem wait if buffer is not empty
        sem_wait(&empty);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        //adding tasks to struct task tasks array for worker/consumer threads to use
        tasks[in] = task;  
        in = (in+1)%buff_size;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        sem_post(&full);
        //incrementing full so that worker threads know that buffer is not empty
        i++;
        //printf("%d tasks completed out of %d tasks\n", counter, number_of_tasks);
        if (counter==number_of_tasks)
            break;
    }  
    //pthread_exit(NULL);
    //waiting for all threads to exit
    //pthread_join(idC, NULL);  
    //printing image
    printf("Draw the image\n");
    DrawImage(pixels, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, "Mandelbrot demo", 3000);

    return 0;
}
```

How to stop the worker thread from being stuck in the loop?

I know the program continues on and displays the correct result but when I call `pthread_join` it keeps on waiting... obviously. How to solve the issue?

Comment: Please post an [mcve] - there is not sufficient code to reproduce. How do start the thread? How do you join?

Comment: Hi! I didn't post the whole code because I thought it might not be necessary but here I have edited the code and added how I create the threads. I knew I was creating the threads perfectly so I thought extra information might just confuse the reader as the rest of it is related to my project

Comment: @4386427 I have edited the code :))

Comment: @4386427 the program just displays an image after the while loop. I was calling pthread_join before that but the program got stuck so I commented it out.

Comment: Don't pass `&index` when creating threads - `index` may change before the thread reads the value.

Comment: @4386427 So how do I display "worker thread 2 has terminated..."

Comment: How is `counter` declared? It looks very suspicious

Comment: I can only repeat - post [mcve] - can't help with the code posted here - sorry

Comment: @4386427 hi ive posted the full code. it works fine only the worker threads are stuck in the loop. else output is perfect. all tasks are completed.

Comment: It seems that the producer only generates `number_of_tasks` events and that **each** consumer expects `number_of_tasks`. Consequently there will not be enough events to stop the consumers. Maybe the producer should make `number_of_tasks * number_of_workers` events

Comment: @4386427 hey that led to a segmentation fault. I'm trying to put more data than there is available

Comment: You should be able to see how many tasks each worker completes. You already have a print

Comment: I know all tasks are bring printed. I want to know how to stop threads from being stuck in sem_wait...

Comment: I don't understand this design.  Most of the work done by the thread is inside the mutex lock?

Comment: I mean, it's kinda usual to lock, dequeue the task quickly and release the lock before doing the work, else the other threads cannot get in and the work gets serialized on the mutex.

Comment: Anyway, the shared globals like 'counter' and 'pixels' are very suspicious, as already commented by others.

Comment: It's cleaner and safer to pass the addess of a task, (&tasks[i]), into the pthread_create call.  This avoids the problem with the index changing before the threads get to dereference it, (as commented by @4386427), and the thread/s then don't need to access the array by index at all.

Comment: If you absolutely must use join() to determine the completion of the tasks, instruct the consumer threads to terminate by adding in an extra 'poison' task at the end, (eg, one with an illegal value, 'start_row=-1', say), that the consumer threads always check for.  If they find it, they push the task back onto the queue and terminate.  All the threads will then get the suicide-request task, terminate and no counting required.

Comment: Hey Martin! Thanks! Good advice to put task outside block and only use critical section to dequeue the task quickly. My program is running at a much much faster rate!

Comment: I also used sem_post(&full) along with break to check if counter==number_of_tasks!
What I wanted to know is that I want to print the value of index to show the time each worker thread creates. How can I do that? @4386427

Comment: @MartinJames Also is it possible that while creating a thread, I make the program sleep so that the index does not change value? I know this might not be good practice but just to confirm.

Comment: @user67989 no, don't do that. Every time a bodge is applied, you wil lhave one more thing to worry aboud when something doesn't work correctly:(